# How to deserialize when only interface is available?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, binary-deserialization

I have three components:

- utility library (Processor.dll): Only knows about Element library
- Element library (IElement): Doesn't know about any library
- App: Knows about both libraries

App calls the Processor library and passes it a class of type:

```
ClassA : IElement
```

ClassA is serialized before being passed to Processor.  Processor is a base library and does not know about class types such as ClassA.  It does know about IElement however.  Processor will deserialize the IElement passed to it, which is of type ClassA.

The issue is that an interface cannot be deserialized.  But Processor does not know about ClassA and should not.  How can I get a reference to the passed in object in this case?

Comment: How are you passing the the "serialized" data to "Processor"? The processor NEEDs to have an implementation of `IElement` to be able to deserialise it. I would definitely reconsider your stance on having a class that is referenced on both sides. Consider creating an `ClassADto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is the create a SerializationBinder implementation that loads classA, then pass a reference to an instance of your binder to Processor.dll so that Processor.dll can use your binder implementation for deserialization. This will allow you to keep the code that references ClassA in the App module (the SerializationBinder implementation will of course have to be defined in the App module).

Here's an example: Given this interface in the Element library

```
public interface IElement
{
    string DoSomething(string param);
}
```

you would define your processor like this:

```
public class ProcessorClass
{
    private SerializationBinder _binder;

    public ProcessorClass(SerializationBinder binder)
    {
        _binder = binder;
    }

    public string CallDoSomething(Stream s)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Binder = _binder;

       var i = (IElement)formatter.Deserialize(s);

        return i.DoSomething("the processor");
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm using a very, very simple serialization binder. Note that this must be defined in the App assembly, that's why you don't need a reference to `ClassA` anywhere besides App.

```
class Binder : SerializationBinder
{
    //WARNING: demonstration only, DO NOT USE in production code
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return Type.GetType("ClassA");
    }
}
```

Then we bring it all together in the App assembly:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

var theObject = new ClassA();

formatter.Serialize(ms, theObject);

var processor = new ProcessorClass(new Binder());

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

string result = processor.CallDoSomething(ms);
```

See this [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder.aspx) for another example of a SerializationBinder.

Comment: From your link, the Deserialize method has a reference to Version2Type.  Since the deserialize is inside Processor.dll, that means Processor will need to know about Version2Type (or ClassA in my case).  Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: The MSDN example uses a concrete type to cast the result of deserialization. In your case, you would cast to the IElement interface instead. I've added some sample code to demonstrate.